# Removing portion of sprite in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, box2d, sprite, cocos2d-x

Is it possible to remove only a portion of a CCSprite that a player comes into contact with?

If a player is running on a tmxtilemap, I'd like to be able to remove only the parts of the tile that the player runs into in an effort to make the look less "boxy".

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, technically no. But you can have it other way round. What you can do is add a particular sprite in parts (with each part as another sprite).then it is possible